# Navbar menu showing down page instead of across the page

Tags: html, navbar, nav

I am very new to all this. I have built a simple nav bar. The problem is that it shows down the page, instead of across the page. How do I get it to show across the page instead? Thank you in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <!--Bootstrap CDN  -->
     <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
   integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <!-- Custom CSS -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

 <!-- nav bar -->
 <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="the-larder-logo.png" width="50" height="50" alt="">
  </a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse show" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Food <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Drink</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Special Events</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: the problem was in  `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse show" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">` this line...just remove the `show` class and you're good to go.

As you're using bootstrap you can use the below code to use as navbar...don't forget to add the scripts for bootstrap.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```